# Is there a way to concatenate the output of a pandas apply into a single multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, multi-index

I have a dataframe with two columns where each of the two columns contains a list indices.  I want to get the product of the two lists on a row by row level to create a multiindex.

For example, df1 below

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        col_a        |        col_b     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       [A1, A2]      |        [B1]      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          [A3]       |      [B2, B3]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

would turn into this:

```
MultiIndex([('A1', 'B1'),
            ('A2', 'B1'),
            ('A3', 'B2'),
            ('A3', 'B3')],
names = ['col_a', 'col_b'], length = 4)
```

What I'm doing right now is the following:

```
my_multiindex = df1.apply(lambda row: pd.MultiIndex.from_product([row["col_a"], row["col_b"]], names = ['col_a', 'col_b']), axis = 1)
```

However, the output of this is looks like:

```
0     MultiIndex([('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B1')])
1     MultiIndex([('A3', 'B2'), ('A3', 'B3')])
```

One object per row, which makes sense since we are using an apply on axis 1.

Is there any way that I can "concatenate" all the output objects into a single multiindex?  Preferably this can be done within the lambda function, but doing it afterwards in a separate step wouldn't be the end of the world.

If you have any suggestions for how to do the overall task (not just the specific "concatenate" step I described) that would be helpful as well.  I've already tried doing this in a for loop using iterrows but that is taking way too long as the size of df1 is about 50K rows, the average length of the list in col_a is 300, and the average length of the list in col_b is 30.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably also the "dumbest": just take products of each row, put them all together, and feed them to `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`.

```
import itertools
rowwise_products = df.apply(
    lambda row: list(itertools.product(*row)),
    axis=1
)
all_tuples = rowwise_products.sum()  # list concatenation

>>> pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(all_tuples, names=df.columns)
MultiIndex([('A1', 'B1'),
            ('A2', 'B1'),
            ('A3', 'B1'),
            ('A3', 'B2'),
            ('A3', 'B3')],
           names=['col_a', 'col_b'])
```

Comment: lol: it looks like we cross-pollinated our answers to converge to essentially the same!  Kudos for your idea of using `.sum()` to flatten all the lists together.

Comment: Thank you!  This did the job for me.  I didn't think to use .sum().  Very clever of you and Pierre D to think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with simple `itertools` version of `product`. Use `product(*row)` to generate the cartesian product (also works if you had more than 2 columns). Then `sum()` and `Multiindex.from_tuples`:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.apply(lambda r: list(product(*r)), axis=1).sum())
```

Comment: This works as well, thank you for posting!